# Fabricate as an offensive spell in Pathfinder

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells

One of my players brought this up. In Pathfinder, Fabricate has a range of close (25 ft. + 5 ft./2 levels) so he thought one could use it to turn worn full-plate into a hollow metal statue with the victim stuck.
Would this work?

Comment: Is the basis of this question assuming that the target in question is already wearing something like full plate, and the caster is going to attempt to Fabricate that full plate into a hollow metal statue?

Comment: Clarification: They are welding(?) joints together to turn it into a statue. and  yes to NFeutz.

Answer (score 6):

While I admire the player's ingenuity, the spell [*fabricate*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/f/fabricate/) has as its material component "the original material, which costs the same amount as the raw materials required to craft the item to be created." [Choosing a Spell](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/#TOC-Choosing-a-Spell) says, "To cast a spell, you must be able to… manipulate the material components…," and material components must typically—such as in this case—be in or at hand to be manipulated. A wizard 9 that casts the spell *fabricate* can't just turn whatever she can see and to which she has line of effect—so long as it's within 45 ft.—into something else of the same material.

To use the question's example, were the wizard's player to *really* want to do this, the wizard's player would have to convince the GM that she's manipulating the warrior's full plate for at least [1 round](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Casting-Time)—not an easy task in the heat of combat!—, then convince the GM that the wizard PC is capable of creating from that full plate a hollow statue that's worth 4,500 gp—likely an item that requires "an appropriate Craft check to fabricate [because it] requir[es] a high degree of craftsmanship" (as per the spell), and the GM, of course, setting that [Craft](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/craft) skill check's DC.

The *fabricate* spell's range "is the maximum distance from [the caster] that the spell’s effect can occur." For example, this range permits the caster to turn a quantity of lumber that the caster can manipulate into a bridge spanning a stream without the caster having to be at *both* the bridge's beginning and end, straddling the stream, when he casts the spell.

Note that the spell *fabricate* is one of the game's most controversial spells, requiring constant GM oversight and allowing a lone unregulated caster to disrupt the economies of a small nation in a matter of weeks. This GM recommends the spell be tightly controlled, likely at least limiting the spell to turning only *raw* materials into finished goods, if not making a house rule that changes the spell's [duration](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/#TOC-Duration) from instantaneous to permanent. (Because this GM finds homebrewing campaigns inconceivable in light of the existence of the spell *fabricate*, this GM often goes a step further and bans the spell outright.)

Comment: Thanks! He's disappointed that it won't function like he wanted.

Comment: Suggestions for improvement welcome.

Answer (score 4):

In order to do this, the caster needs not have an enemy wearing a suit of full-plate, but rather an appropriate quantity of steel on hand (i.e. a third the value of the steel statue that is the finished product).  The range does not specify the range at which the material components are consumed, but rather the range at which the finished product is created.

Provided the caster has the necessary material components they can attempt this, but there are two major obstacles to its success:

> A creature or object brought into being or transported to your location by a conjuration spell cannot appear inside another creature or object, nor can it appear floating in an empty space. It must arrive in an open location on a surface capable of supporting it.

(from the conjuration school rules).

This means that you can't encase the target in a nearly-skin-tight statue, since their space is not an 'open location', probably (open location isn't actually defined).  You *could*, however, encase the target in a much larger statue that merely contained them, rather than restricting their motion entirely.

The other problem is that, while *Fabricate* typically affects 10 ft<sup>3</sup> per caster level of material, it only affects 1 cubic foot per caster level of material if the material is metal (or anything else in the mineral kingdom, which is most things you'll work with besides wood) a cube 5ft to a side has a volume of 125 ft<sub>3</sub>, which would require a CL of 125.  That's not usually feasible in-combat, to say the least.  Instead, we can make a hollow cube with side-length 5 and no bottom, but the weight of this container may not be enough to trap opponents.

At CL 20 the container, if made of steel, weighs 9,780 pounds and has roughly 60 hit points to a side, being about 2 inches thick.  This is at least an inconvenience to any medium-sized creature with no way to burrow, and a strength score less than 44.  A creature with at least 38 strength can toss the containment off itself as a full-round action, and a creature with at least 31 strength can still move around by pushing against the walls of the container, though it can't remove the container by means of its strength.  Any situation that modifies encumbrance can make the required strengths lower or higher, but the strength scores are generally pretty high, but not unheard of for a creature of that level.

At CL 9, the minimum for the spell, the wall is a little less than an inch thick and has maybe 25 hp.  It weighs just under half as much, so the strength needed will be around 5-6 points lower, which scales the requirements down to pretty high, but not unheard of for creatures expected around 9th level.

If the creature is Large, we need a thin, 10-ft-to-a-side hollow cube. This does not change the weight of the container, but it reduces its hp to a quarter the usual value, or 15 hp for a CL 20 caster and 6 for a CL 9 caster.  This means even extremely weak large creatures can probably break out with a single attack.  Furthermore, the strength scores required are reduced by 5, or 15 if the creature is a Large quadruped.  At CL 20 this means your container can barely contain one CR 3 lion (which would still be able to slide the container around), and a CR 5 Dire Lion could free itself with a full action.

If the creature is Tiny or smaller, the container *might* be able to be smaller than 5 ft, but probably not in combat.  You could trap several such creatures at once, though.  The Strength scores required, at least, are higher, which couples well with the fact most such creatures have very low Strength scores.

So, in conclusion, you *can* use *fabricate* offensively to trap corporeal opponents, so long as they cannot burrow, teleport, or plane shift, are of medium size or smaller, not extraordinarily damaging, and are either not extraordinarily strong for a creature of your level or no bigger than Tiny.

Most creatures who willingly don Full Plate indeed meet the above requirements, and so the spell may well be able to be used offensively to completely negate them, given that it has no saving throw permitted and requires no attack roll.  This usage of the spell is situationally effective, but certainly not overuseful. Also it costs you a casting of *Fabricate*, which you could otherwise use to create fabulous riches neigh unending.  Note that using steel for this plan is a terrible idea, since using adamantine both recoups your losses from using the spell offensively and makes the container considerably more durable, though not quite heavy enough to reliably contain Large creatures moderately lower level than you.

Answer (score -1):

#### No.

The materials to be manipulated by the spell are the (M) components of the spell. You must have the materials at hand in your possession to be able to cast it, and something worn or attended by an enemy is not available.

[source](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic):

> To cast a spell, you must be able to [...] manipulate the material components or focus (if any).

[source](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/f/fabricate/):

> **Components:** V, S, M (the original material, which costs the same amount as the raw materials required to craft the item to be created)